# JOSE jwe/jws payload

Tags: security, jwt, json-web-token, jwe

Is it possible to have any kind of payload when using JOSE?

I was thinking of doing something like:
{"alg":"ES512",
 "cty":"XML"
}

and just make a string out of the XML file, on the server side I check cty and create the XML.

I'm pretty sure its possible, but I didn't see any example so I started thinking that maybe that's not the idea behind jose and that cty is only meant to indicate payload is a JWT or something related to jose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see from http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515.txt:

> `JWS Payload`
> The sequence of octets to be secured -- a.k.a. the message.  The
> payload can contain an arbitrary sequence of octets.

So your hunch is right. And as indicated in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515#section-4.1.10, the `cty` element can be used to indicate XML content following http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml with the ommission of the `application/` prefix. So `xml` would be appropriate in your case but in (the regular) case that both the sender and the receiver know that they're going to exchange XML, the `cty` element can be omitted.

For JWE's it is the same. There's an example with non-JSON plaintext here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7516#appendix-A.3